# Como chamar um método que está dentro do meu Fragment através do onclick de um button que também está dentro do fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, onclick

Como chamar um método que está dentro da minha fragment pelo java através do onclick de um button contido na mesma fragment? Segue código:

public class FragmentMinhaConta extends Fragment {

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_minhaconta, null);
    Button botao = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.editarMinhasInformacoes);

    return (view);
}

public void clicar(View v){
    mostrarMsg("Titulo teste", "Mensagem teste");
}

public void mostrarMsg(String titulo, String mensagem) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(titulo);
    builder.setMessage(mensagem);
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa usar o OnClickListener no botão, dessa forma:

```
botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mostrarMsg("Titulo teste", "Mensagem teste");
   }
});
```

Não tem necessidade de chamar o método clicar(), você pode chamar direto o método que exibe a mensagem.

Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado. Resolveu meu problema.